# Registering Launcher to accept Pinned Shortcuts

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher, android-8.0-oreo, pinned-shortcut

I am creating a custom Android launcher. I want it to support Pinned Shortcuts. When calling `ShortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()`, it returns `false` even though my custom launcher is the default. What do I need to do in order to allow my launcher to accept pinned shortcuts? Is there a permission missing?

Comment: had any luck with that?

Comment: Not so far, but I'm not actively searching anymore.

Comment: Hi @hellowill89, Had any solution or findings?